# Java: array methods

Tags: java, arrays

This code supposedly checks an array of integers for 9's and returns it's frequency but the method is not being recognized. Any help please to make this code work.

```
public static int arrayCount9(int[] nums) {
      int count = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 9) {
          count++;
        }
      }

      return count;
};


public static void main(String[]args){

    System.out.println(arrayCount9({1,2,9}));

}
```

Comment: In the future instead of just saying "it's not working", provide more detailed information - if you're getting an error message please provide it.  If not then explain what led you to believe that it isn't working the way it should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your method call to the following:

```
System.out.println(arrayCount9(new int[]{1,2,9}));
```

Alternatively:

```
int[] a = {1,2,9};
System.out.println(arrayCount9(a));
```

The shortcut syntax `{1,2,9}` can only be used when initializing an array type. If you pass this notation to a method, it will not be interpreted it as an array by the compiler.

Comment: Because you're not writing Javascript.